# Left Outer Calendar Table Join with LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

How can I write the following `LEFT OUTER JOIN` SQL query against my `Calendar` and `Sales` tables for the purpose of grouping summed sales by day, week or month in LINQ so that it can be materialised by LINQ-to-SQL?

```
SELECT c.CalendarDate, c.FirstDayOfWeek, c.FirstDayOfMonth,
       ISNULL(s.Total, 0) as Total
FROM Calendar as c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales as s
 on s.SaleDate >= c.CalendarDateTime and
    s.SaleDate < c.NextDayDateTime
WHERE s.SaleDate BETWEEN @since and @until
```

I managed to get an *inner join* working in LINQ, but I need an outer join to retrieve days with zero sales. Here is the code I use for an inner join:

```
var sales = from s in db.Sales
            from c in db.Calendars
            where
                s.SaleDate >= c.CalendarDate && s.SaleDate < c.NextDayDateTime
                && s.SaleDate >= sinceDate && s.SaleDate < dateEnd
            select new
            {
                c.CalendarDate,
                c.FirstDateOfWeek,
                c.FirstDateOfMonth,
                s.Total
            };
```

I can then switch on a date interval and group sales as follows:

Daily:

```
var groupedSales = sales.GroupBy(x => x.CalendarDate);
```

Weekly:

```
var groupedSales = sales.GroupBy(x => x.FirstDateOfWeek);
```

Monthly:

```
var groupedSales = sales.GroupBy(x => x.FirstDateOfMonth);
```

Finally:

```
var salesReport = from g in groupedSales
                  orderby g.Key
                  select new {
                      Date = g.Key,
                      Total = g.Sum(x => x.Total)
                  };
```

Alternatively, it could also work to inject zero sale records into my report after retrieving sales for non-zero days only.

Comment: Your SQL statement won't run a LEFT OUTER JOIN as you use the Sales table in your WHERE statement other than for a NULL check.

Comment: @cjk, fixed. Thanks for pointing that out (I have it like that on my end). Maybe if I add a ?? to my LINQ query it will infer the left outer join?

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var sales = from s in db.Sales
            from c in db.Calendars.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where
                s.SaleDate >= c.CalendarDate && s.SaleDate < c.NextDayDateTime
                && s.SaleDate >= sinceDate && s.SaleDate < dateEnd
```

**EDIT:**
You can create helper classes like this:

```
class CalendarSealesHelper
{
   public DateTime CalendarDate {get; set;}
   public DateTime NextDayDateTime {get; set;}
}

class CalendarSealesHelperComparer : IEqualityComparer<CalendarSealesHelper>
{
    public bool Equals(CalendarSealesHelper c1, CalendarSealesHelper c2)
    {
        if (c2.CalendarDate >= c1.CalendarDate 
               && c2.NextDayDateTime < c1.NextDayDateTime)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public int GetHashCode(CalendarSealesHelper c)
    {
        int hCode = (int)c.CalendarDate.Ticks ^ (int)c.NextDayDateTime.Ticks;
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then try this:

```
var query = db.Calendars.GroupJoin(
         db.Sales,
         c => new CalendarSealesHelper{c.CalendarDate, c.NextDayDateTime},
         s => new CalendarSealesHelper{s.SaleDate, s.SaleDate},
         (c, s) => new {Calendars = c, Sales = s},
         new CalendarSealesHelperComparer())
    .SelectMany(s => s.Sales.DefaultIfEmpty(),
            (c, s) => new {
                            CalendarDate = c.CalendarDate,
                            FirstDayOfWeek = c.FirstDayOfWeek,
                            FirstDayOfMonth = c.FirstDayOfMonth,
                            Total = s.Total,
                            SaleDate = s.SaleDate
                          })
    .Where(r => r.SaleDate >= sinceDate && r.SaleDate <= dateEnd);
```

Comment: `db.Calendar.DefaultIfEmpty()` generates a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for Calendar with `ON 1=1`, but unfortunately not on the date ranges. Tried switching it and on both, but neither works.

Comment: Thanks Hamlet. Unfortunately the GroupJoin throws a `NotSupportedException`: "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'GroupJoin'." I don't think it's possible to materialize the custom comparer to SQL.

Comment: I believe, that is possible. Can you provide me any test data and db scheme by script (used tables)?